# Python for loop takes over hours, how to reduce execution time?

Tags: python, for-loop, time, execution

I'm using a for loop to get a particular financial data (around 800 sets) from yfinance.
But the running time for this execution is over an hour!
This is just a small part of my whole project.
How to reduce the execution time?

[for loop code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9fva.png)

==========================================

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Do you understand that every call to `yf.Ticker(i)` involves a networked web server transaction?  Those take time.  Sometimes LOTS of time.  And you're doing that TWICE for each symbol.  At the very least, cache the result and use the cache to build the DataFrame.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yfinance` doesn't appear to have a native way to parallel download institutional holders, so we can work our own with `pandarellel`~

A parallelized version:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from pandarallel import pandarallel

pandarallel.initialize(nb_workers=16, progress_bar=True)

t = yf.Tickers([x for x in tqdm(symbol['Symbol'])])
def get_holders(x):
    try:
        return x.institutional_holders.head()
    except:
        pass


call = pd.Series(t.tickers).parallel_apply(get_holders)
df = pd.concat(call.to_dict())
df
```

(text Output Same as below)

Here, Downloading the whole S&P 500 in 4 minutes:
[image: S&P500]

---

```
import yfinance as yf

# symbols = [x for x in tqdm(symbol['Symbol'])]

symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT'] # Testing only, Swap for yours

tickers = yf.Tickers(' '.join(symbols))

institutional_holders = {x:tickers.tickers[x].institutional_holders.head() for x in symbols}

df = pd.concat(institutional_holders)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                               Holder      Shares Date Reported   % Out         Value
AAPL 0     Vanguard Group, Inc. (The)  1261261357    2021-12-30  0.0779  223962179162
     1                 Blackrock Inc.  1019810291    2021-12-30  0.0630  181087713372
     2        Berkshire Hathaway, Inc   887135554    2021-12-30  0.0548  157528660323
     3       State Street Corporation   633115246    2021-12-30  0.0391  112422274232
     4                       FMR, LLC   352204129    2021-12-30  0.0218   62540887186
MSFT 0     Vanguard Group, Inc. (The)   615950062    2021-12-30  0.0824  207156324851
     1                 Blackrock Inc.   519035634    2021-12-30  0.0694  174562064426
     2       State Street Corporation   302541869    2021-12-30  0.0405  101750881382
     3                       FMR, LLC   215377233    2021-12-30  0.0288   72435671002
     4  Price (T.Rowe) Associates Inc   204196901    2021-12-30  0.0273   68675501744
```

Answer (score 0):

How many columns do you have? Instead of creating dataframes for every iteration, I'd use a dictionary to store the column values, append the dictionary in a list. And after the loop, make a dataframe from the list of dictionary.

```
d = []

for i in tqdm(symbol['Symbol']:
    dict_store = {}
    try:
        dict_store['col_1'] = value1
        dict_store['col_2'] = value2
        dict_store['col_3'] = value3
    except:
        dict_store['col_1'] = ''
        dict_store['col_2'] = ''
        dict_store['col_3'] = ''

    d.append(dict_store)
```

if the list is d, holding multiple dictionaries, then:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```